# PyEZ - Cron Job to connect to 8 routers and save the running config to 8 local files at a specific time stamp

Tags: python, cron, pyez

I am a starter to PyEZ. Can I write a cron job in PyEZ which will connect to 8 routers and fetch the running Config on device and save to 8 different files at a particular timestamp. Could you help me achieve the same.

I have already written a PyEZ code which will write the Base config to my local file.

Loading the config files to local file

from jnpr.junos import Device
from lxml import etree
dev = Device(host='hostname',port='22',user='root', password='sitlab123!' )
dev.open()class Create_Config():

```
def __init__(self):

    cnf = dev.rpc.get_config() ####Get Config as Str
            with open('myfile.txt', "w") as text_file:

            text_file.write(etree.tostring(cnf))

            text_file.close()

#####Return Configuration

def get_conf(self):

    return dev.cli("show configuration")
```

Comment: Here is one example: https://github.com/dmontagner/jnpr-router-cfg-collection For the cron part, I recommend you to either use the Linux crontab or other automation frameworks like SaltStack. For simplicity, use the crontab from Linux.

Comment: Thanks , It works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python-crontab module along with PyEZ module.

[Python-crontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab)

To create a new cron job is as follows:

```
from crontab import CronTab
#init cron
cron   = CronTab()

#add new cron job
job  = cron.new(command='/usr/bin/echo')

#job settings
job.hour.every(4)
```